# extracting the sum of numbers from a vector of strings in R after using str_extract_all()

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a poorly formatted data frame with a vector of strings, e.g.

```
f<-data.frame(FruitQuantity=c("10 apple", "orange(15), bananas(30)", "cucumber-15",0,"not sure",NA))


> f
            FruitQuantity
1                10 apple
2 orange(15), bananas(30)
3             cucumber-15
4                       0
5                not sure
6                    <NA>
```

from which I wish to extract the sum of count data into another vector like so:

```
             FruitQuantity Total
1                10 apple    10
2 orange(15), bananas(30)    45
3             cucumber-15    15
4                       0     0
5                not sure    NA
6                    <NA>    NA
```

To extract the numeric data, I did the following

```
library(tidyverse)

f$SeperateCount<-str_extract_all(f$FruitQuantity,"\\d+")
```

Resulting:

```
>f
            FruitQuantity SeperateCount
1                10 apple            10
2 orange(15), bananas(30)        15, 30
3             cucumber-15            15
4                       0             0
5                not sure              
6                    <NA>            NA

> f$SeperateCount
[[1]]
[1] "10"

[[2]]
[1] "15" "30"

[[3]]
[1] "15"

[[4]]
[1] "0"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
[1] NA
```

it returned a list, which contains within it lists of numbers extracted as characters, e.g. `c(15,30)` in the second row and `character(0)` in the fifth row

to obtain the sum of elements in each list, I tried the following

```
f$Total<-sapply(f$SeperateCount,sum)
```

an error returned

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Then I tried converting the characters in the list into intergers

```
f$SeperateCountNumeric<-lapply(f$SeperateCount, function(x) if(all(grepl('^[0-9.]+$', x))) as.integer(x) else x)

> f$SeperateCountNumeric
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 15 30

[[3]]
[1] 15

[[4]]
[1] 0

[[5]]
integer(0)

[[6]]

[1] NA

> f
            FruitQuantity SeperateCount SeperateCountNumeric
1                10 apple            10                   10
2 orange(15), bananas(30)        15, 30               15, 30
3             cucumber-15            15                   15
4                       0             0                    0
5                not sure                                   
6                    <NA>            NA                   NA
```

but even after conversion to interger, the same character error still persists

```
> sapply(f$SeperateCountNumeric,sum)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

are there any alternative ways of doing this?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the package `stringr` you can try this

```
library(stringr)

f$Total <- sapply(str_extract_all(f$FruitQuantity, "[[:digit:]]+"),
  function(x) ifelse(identical(x, character(0)),NA,sum(as.numeric(x))))

f
            FruitQuantity Total
1                10 apple    10
2 orange(15), bananas(30)    45
3             cucumber-15    15
4                       0     0
5                not sure    NA
6                    <NA>    NA
```

A similar **base R** solution

```
f$Total <- sapply(strsplit(trimws(
  gsub("[[:alpha:](),-]","", f$FruitQuantity)), " "),
    function(x) ifelse(identical(x, character(0)),
                       NA,sum(as.numeric(x))))

f
            FruitQuantity Total
1                10 apple    10
2 orange(15), bananas(30)    45
3             cucumber-15    15
4                       0     0
5                not sure    NA
6                    <NA>    NA
```

Comment: That solved it! thanks a lot!